# Imagine a canal going around the globe, if there's a leak somewhere does all the water flow through that, making the canal empty?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, gravity, pressure, flow

Assume globe is perfect sphere and canal is built above the ground. I've thought about this but can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Is the canal parallel to the equator, or does it go at an angle? The rotation of the earth makes the equipotential surfaces not quite perfect spheres. This doesn't matter if you're at a constant line of latitude, but it does matter if you're going around "at an angle."

Comment: Anyway if you ignore the rotation of the earth, it will definitely empty through the hole!.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the canal is perfectly circular. With a perfect sphere of uniform density and either no spin, or if the sphere has spin but the canal is along the equator, then yes all of the water could eventually leak out. However Earth is not exactly of uniform density which causes minor gravitational variances at different points on Earth"s surface. So there would be places in the canal, even along the equator, where gravity is slightly stronger that would hold some water.